# First N columns in dataframe using PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

How to select first N column in a data frame and make it into another data frame?

There is DF with 180 columns and I want to create another DF with first 105 columns with out implicitly mention the column name in the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of column names from `df.columns`, and select the first 105 values in the list:

```
df2 = df.select(df.columns[:105])
```

But since you tagged it with scala too, here's a scala solution:

```
val df2 = df.select(df.columns.take(105).map(col): _*)
```